# How to check if last command line argument is a valid digit - C programming

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am trying to write a program which will check a text file, but also uses a number which is the last argument passed. I want to do some error checking to make sure that the last argument is a digit.

Comment: What is `digit`?

Comment: `isdigit((usigned char)argv[argc-1][0]) && (argv[argc-1][1] == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

### ORIGINAL

I do not know what is the `digit()` function, but whatever this function is, it will never check if the string `argv[argc-1]` is a digit successfully. That is because the `atoi()` function will return zero if `argv[argc-1]` is not a numeric string as an error, but will also return zero if `argv[argc-1]` is `"0"`.
To verify if `argv[argc-1]` is one and only one digit, you need to:

1. Check the length of the string (`argv[argc-1][1] == '\0'`);
2. Check if the first character is a digit character (`isdigit( argv[argc-1][0] )`).

Here is the final code.

```
char *a = argv[argc-1];
if ( (a[1] != '\0') || !isdigit(a[0]) ) {
    printf("No valid digit entered\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

### EDIT #1

My original answer has two problems, as some users mentioned below.

In first place, I assumed that strings in `argv` cannot be empty. However, if a program is called like `./program ""`, `argv[1]` is going to be an empty string.

For demonstration purpose, here is a program that prints in `stdout` all `argv` strings and their lengths.

```
/* program.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("strlen(\"%s\") = %zu\n", argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the output, confirming `argv[1]` is an empty string.

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o program program.c
$ ./program ""
strlen("./program") = 9
strlen("") = 0
$
```

The second problem is related to the usage of `isdigit()` function. According to the manual (`man isdigit` on terminal), the argument passed to `isdigit()` must me an `unsigned char`.

```
int isdigit(int c);
```

> These  functions  check  whether c, which must have the value of an
> unsigned char or EOF, falls into a certain character class  according
> to the  specified  locale.

Here is the final solution without the problems mentioned in the comments below.

```
char *a = argv[argc-1];
if ( !isdigit((unsigned char) a[0]) || (a[1] != '\0') ) {
    printf("No valid digit entered\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Pedantic concern:  Reverse the order: `!isdigit(a[0])` first to prevent testing beyond the _null chracter_ .  Although unusual to have an argv[] with length 0, possible in some cases (as in a call to `main()`.  IAC, more idiomatic to test the first array element of `a[]` before the next.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, yes. In this case there is no problem, because there is no way for a string in `argv` to be empty, unless you changed it. And if you changed it, you would know. In other situations, it would be better to use the `strlen()` function. But knowing that a string in `argv` will always have, at least, two characters, why not test the second character directly?

Comment: And the `isdigit()` function probably evaluates more than one expression. So, if the size does not fit, the program will not need to evaluate if the first character code is between the ranges where a character is considered a digit.

Comment: @MiguelCarvalho `there is no way for a string in argv to be empty, unless you changed it`: that's not correct. It isn't prohibited in C. It's quite possible argv[i] to point an empty string. For instance, the program can be called like that: `./program ""` and `argv[1]` will point to an empty string.

Comment: Also, the argument to `isdigit` needs to be converted to `unsigned char` to avoid the risk of undefined behavior.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin, I didn't know `./program ""` would make `argv[1]` an empty string. I will change my original answer to solve this problem.

Comment: `"%ld\n"`,does not certainly match the the type `size_t` from `strlen()`.  Better to use `"%zu\n"`.

Comment: *That is because the `atoi()` function will return zero if `argv[argc-1]` is not a numeric string as an error*  [No, it's even worse than that](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1p1): "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined."  It might return zero.  Or it could just as well return 42 in 7.5 million years...